# How to access the localhost of my android phone from my laptop?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vnc

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running in Termux app on localhost:1 port. I can use this Ubuntu in graphical mode using vnc viewer app.
How can I access this port on my laptop (which is connected to the same network as the phone) to run Ubuntu in vnc viewer on laptop?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use Hamachi to create VPN under your network: https://www.vpn.net/

Comment: Perhaps you could update this answer with details on how OP could achieve what you suggest?